# How to sort frequencies and percentages in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 100 columns and here is part of my sample:

```html
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
                     "outcome   night   book    color
0   0   1   1
1   0   1   1
1   1   1   1
1   1   0   1
1   0   1   1
"
)
```

I want to calculate the frequency and percentages to get the following table.Thanks for your help

```html
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
                     "result    N1  N0  %p1 %p0
outcome 4   0   80  20
night   2   3   40  60
book    4   1   80  20
color   5   0   100 0

"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
tibble::tibble(result = names(df), 
               N1 = colSums(df), N0 = colSums(!df), 
               p1 = N1/nrow(df) * 100, p0 = N0/nrow(df) * 100)

#  result     N1    N0    p1    p0
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 outcome     4     1    80    20
#2 night       2     3    40    60
#3 book        4     1    80    20
#4 color       5     0   100     0
```